# For $x\in\mathbb R$. Prove that there exists $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $m<x<n$

Tags: real-analysis

> For $x\in\mathbb R$. Prove that there exists $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $m<x<n$.

Assume that $m < n$. I apply first Archimedian property to get $x < n$. But I need to show that $m < x$ to complete proof?

Could you provide some hints?

Comment: I'm confused are you trying to prove for any m < n there exist an x such that m < x < n, or are you trying to prove for any x there are m, n such that m < x < n.  You say you assume m < n.  well, if you have to prove they exist you shouldn't assume anything about them before you know they exist.  Then you say you prove x < n.  How?  If you are assuming n and x exist you can't conclude anything about their relation.  If you mean you prove by archimedian there exists n > x why can't you use archemedian to prove there exists m < x?  What is the statement of the Archemedian?

Comment: @fleablood So i can directly apply archimedian property without assuming m and n.Archimedian property says that if x>0 and y $\in$ R then there exists $n$ such that $nx>y$,

Comment: Well you *can't* assume $m$ and $n$.  What if it turns out that $m < n < x$? You have an $x$ to start with.  You need to show two things.  There is an $n > x$ and there is an $m < x$.  "$m$" and "$n$" are just labels so it's not a matter of "assuming" $m < n$; that will follow *after* you find the numbers.  If you "assume" $m < n$ **before** you've proven that $n> x$ and $m < x$ then that means you are assigning some value to them.

Comment: According to Rudin's "Principals of Mathematical Analysis" that is half of what the Archimedian property is formally stated to be.  A different text will state it differently.  What does the archimedian property mean to *you*?  Other consequences of Archimedian property are "between any two reals there is a rational".  The consequences that for any two integer a, b there are unique integers q,r so that a = bxq + r; 0 <= r < b, and that for any real x there exist an integer m <= x < m+1 are so basic that often people simply say "by the archimedian property" .... to be continued....

Comment: @fleablood i only know the one version of it which i mentioned in my comment

Comment: ...continued...  So when you say "I know by AP the there is an $n > x$ but how do I show there is an $m < x$" I'm not entirely how *you* used the AP property to get $n > x$ nor why *you* can't similarly use the AP to find $m < x$.  So my two question for you are:  1) When **you** say "the archimedian property" in your own words, what does that mean?  2) How did you use it to show there is an n > x?

Comment: Which comment?  "Archimedian property says that if x>0 and y ∈ R then there exists n such that nx>y"?

Comment: Okay, basically the archimedian property says "if x is a non-zero numer, no matter how small, you can find an integer large enough to 'blow it up' as big as you'd like".  So if $x = 1$ that means "the integers can be as big as I'd like.  So for any $y$ there is are integers  that are bigger than $y$.  Okay, what is the *smallest* integer that is bigger than $y$? Call it $n$.  Then $n >y$ and $n-1 \le y$ and $n-2 < y$.  We are done...  **!!EXCEPT!!** ... how do we know there **IS** a smallest integer bigger than $y$?

Comment: @fleablood you are confusing me

Comment: Well, *why* does the archimedian principal work in the first place?  Because the integers are unbounded.  That's intuitively obvious.  Or we can prove it using the least upper bound property of the Real Numbers. Either way.  If $y$ is smaller than all possible integers then $-y$ is bigger than all possible integers.  But by the AP that is impossible. So for any $y$ there are integers larger than it (by the AP), there are integers smaller than it (by the AP applied to -y). Pick any two larger and smaller. If you pick smallest and largest of each you get $m \le x \le n$ **and** $m=n-1$!

Comment: Okay.  Question 1:  Why does the AP say that there is an $n > y$?

Comment: @fleablood there is proof of this using lub axiom

Comment: Okay, If the reals have the lub axiom it can be proven that the reals also have the greatest lower bound property.  Have you seen that?  If y is bigger than all integers we can prove that is impossible by lub property.  But if y is smaller than all integers we can prove that is impossible the exact same way with the greatest lower bound property.  [Basically if y is bigger than all integers, then the integers have a lub, find an integer by the lub and add 1 and you get an integer larger than the lub which is impossible.  So there is an integer larger than y]..tbc...

Comment: ... [so if y is smaller than all integers, then the integers have a greatest lower bound.  find an integer close to the greatest lower bound and subtract 1. You get an integer smaller than the greatest lower bound which is impossible.  So there is an integer smaller than y.]

Comment: @fleablood hmm this is much more intuitive way to prove this question. Thanks. you mean to say that no real can be upper bound for integers. So there must exist some real less than integer

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to say.  Well, actually I meant there must exist some integer greater than any real.  And contrariwise, no real can be a *lower* bound so there exist some integer less than any real.  But even stronger.  If you take the upper bound of all integers < y and the lower bound of all integers > y, you get the *stronger* result that for any real x, you can find integers m, and m+1 so that $m\le x\le m+1$.

Comment: @fleablood So i will now write about what i understand from your comments.So i have to prove that there is real(say x) such that $x <m$. So let me assume that this is not the case and so, $x>m$ fro any m in set of natural numbers. But this will mean that set of natural numbers is bounded. So i have a contrdiction because by archimedian property i can find n>(any real). So x<m. Now i am done with half part. Now i am to show that there exists a $n$ such that $n<x$.If say that there does not exist any $n$ such that n<x.so for all n they are  > x. so for all n i have x<n. SO x is lower bound for n

Comment: @fleablood so $x<n$ and also $x<n+1$ so subtracting these two i get 0<-1. This is contradiction. Is this right? Thanks

Comment: 0 < 1 isn't a contradiction.

Comment: @fleablood it is $0<-1$

Comment: You don't get 0 < -1 if you subtract you get x - n < 0 < 1 which is not a contradiction.  But I don't see how you got x < n and x < n+1.

Comment: @fleablood all n's are bigger than x. so n+1 is also a natural number and so > x.

Comment: You keep trying to start with a fixed integer m or n and trying to find x based on it.  That is the exact opposite of what is being asked.  START with the x.  Prove there is an integer larger than it.  And don't worry what you name it.  m and n are just labels.  Start fix and name the REAL x and then show there is an integer larger than it and an integer smaller than it.

Comment: Um, what do you mean all n are greater than x?  What if x = 27.367 and n =16? Some integers are larger and some are smaller.  That's the entire point of what you are trying to prove.  Why are you talking about natural numbers instead of integers?

Comment: @fleablood The helf part is correct or not which proves that x<n. Now i am to apply glb property to get other half

Comment: @fleablood okay let me think some time more and then i will reply

Comment: Let $x = \pi^{395}$.  Let $y = 1$ then the AP says there is an integer n so that $n*1=n > \pi^{395} $.  Take the set of all integers bigger than $\pi^{395} $.  Let k be the smallest such interger.  So $k > \pi^{395} $.  Now consider $k-1$ it's smaller than k that is the smallest such integer.  So $k-1 \le \pi^{395} < k $.

Comment: @fleablood So in my question i have $m=n-1$ as far as your previous comment.

Comment: n can be any integer you want so long as it's bigger than x.  And m can be any integer you want so long as it is less than x.  There's not just one m and n.  There are infinite numbers of them. If x < n.  Then x < n+1.  And x < n+2.  Etc.  If m < x, then m-1 < x.  And m-2 < x.  Etc.  But think about it.  There must be a smallest such n and a largest such m.  You can zoom in and find some m' that's the largest integer that's less or equal to x and some n' that's the smallest integer that is bigger than x.  So m' $\le $ x < n' and m' = n' -1.

Comment: In other words.  Every real number is between two adjacent integers.  That shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 3):

From the wording, it looks as if we can assume that the reals have the Archimedean property. So there is a natural number $n$ such that $x\lt n$. It remains to deal with the "$m$" part of the assertion.

If $x\ge 0$, let $m=-1$. Then $m\lt x\lt n$.

Now suppose that $x\lt 0$. There  is a natural number $w$ such that $|x|=-x\lt w$. Let $m=-w$. Show that $m\lt x$.

Comment: Since $-x < w$ and $m=-w$. so put $w=-m$ in inequality i get $x>m$

Comment: But i do not get idea of proof.

Comment: @Gathdi:  You comment finishes things. You have proved that there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m\lt x\lt n$ in the remaining case $x\lt 0$. If you want I will write a slightly neater (more symmetric) version that you may prefer.

Comment: I have seen proof that between any two reals there is a rational and this proof is different than that. I am confused on what is general method to proofs of these kinds.

Comment: The theorem you refer to in your previous comment (the rationals are dense in the reals) is quite different, and naturally has a proof that has little connection with the proof of the current theorem. The only thing in common is that both use the Archimedean property. The $m\lt x\lt n$ theorem is *very close* to the Archimedean property.  As you saw, one just has to add a little to take care of negative $x$. The proof of denseness of the rationals in the reals takes more work.

Comment: Just one thing, have you seen proof of this before or you thought it just now. i am asking before i am not able to do proofs

Comment: @Gathdi: I had not seen this specifically, but we both have used the fact that multiplication by $-1$ reverses inequalities many times. Here is another way of thinking about things. For $x\gt 0$ we can use $m=0$. For $x\lt 0$, write down suitable $m'$ and $n'$ for $-x$, and multiply by $-1$. As always, a sketch (number line here) is useful in designing a proof. Once we see what's going on geometrically, with practice the formal part is not too hard to write.

Answer (score 1):

So what is the statement of the archemedian property.

By my book it is:a) for $x, y \in \mathbb R$, $x > 0$ then there is positive integer such that $nx > y$ b) for $x, y \in \mathbb R$, $x < y$ there exists $q\in \mathbb Q$ so that $x < q <y$.

We won't use b.

So for any $y$, $1 > 0$ there exist $n > |y|$. So $-n < -|y|$.

So either $y \ge 0$ and $|y| = y$ and $y > -y$ and $-n < -y < y < n$ and $-n < y < n$, ore $y \le 0$ and $|y| = -y$ and $-y > y$ and $-n < -|y| = y < |y| = -y < n$ and $-n < y < n$.

Which is actually a very weak and unsatisfying result.  We *know* there exists an $n$ so that $n \le x < n+1$.

It might be a good idea to understand *why* the archemdiean principal holds and that it could just as easily been written as: for all $x \in \mathbb R$ there is an $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n \le x < n + 1$.

Let $S = \{n \in \mathbb Z| n < x$.  If $S$ is empty then $x$ is a lower bound for $\mathbb Z$.  Let $v \inf \mathbb Z$.  Then for any $0 < \epsilon < 1$ there is a $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $v \le n < v + \epsilon$.  But then $v - 1 \le n - 1  < v - 1 + \epsilon < v$.  But $n-1 \in \mathbb Z$ and $n-1 < \inf \mathbb Z$ which is a contradiction.

This proves there are integers below $x$ and also that $\mathbb Z$ is not bounded below.  An exact equivalent argument  can show $\mathbb Z$ is not bounded above and there are integers above $x$.

So that proves your weak statement.  But what about my strong statement that there exist $n$ so that $n \le x < n+1$.

If $x \in \mathbb Z$ this is trivial: $n = x < n+1$.

So let's assume $x \not \in \mathbb Z$.

Let's go back to our  $S = \{m \in \mathbb Z| m > x\}$ and $v = \inf S$.  $x$ is lower bound so $x \le v$.  If $v$ is greatest lower bound, s for any $0 < \epsilon < 1$ there is an $n \in \mathbb Z$ so that $v \le n < v+ \epsilon$.  If $v < n$ then that exist another integer $n_2$ so that $v \le n_2 < n$. But $0 < n - n_2 < \epsilon < 1$ which is impossible.  So $v \in \mathbb Z$.  And $x \le v$ and $v - 1 \not \in S$ so $v-1 \le x \le v$.

Which if $x \not \in \mathbb Z$ proves $n = v-1 < x < v= n+1$.

And if $x \in \mathbb Z$ we trivially have $n = x < n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr

If you can assume that the integers are not bounded above or below then that means for any $x \in \mathbb R$ that $x$ is neither an upper bound nor a lower bound of the integers.

Thus there are integers larger and smaller than $x$.

====

Now to actually **prove** the integers are not bounded is another issue altogether....